Github Markdown highlights text with @ in it
I am writing documentation using Github Markdown for Objective-C, and everytime I write @weakify(self) or strongify(self) and publish my documentation, these two writings appear in highlighted red and the text is white.
In Github preview everything seems fine, yet when I publish it and go to the documentation website, I see that red highlight.

This is how I am writing my documentation (I found on the internet that objc is how I should mark that the code is in Objective-C, I tried using objective-c, but then the code is just plain grey):
```objc
@weakify(self);
[self.bannerAdUnit fetchDemandWithAdObject:gamRequest completion:^(enum ResultCode resultCode)        { 
  @strongify(self);
}];


By default GitHub uses Jekyll to build github.io pages and this renders Markdown differently than on the github.com page.
To overcome another such difference (Jekyll does not allow HTML markup like <li> inside Markdown table cells), I switched the page builder workflow from Jekyll to pandoc on the GitHub repo (see https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-vocabularies/blob/main/.github/workflows/gh-pages.yml). Perhaps you can do something similar.
Both github.com and pandoc 3.1.13 highlight your code properly, but only when I enclose it in ```objectivec instead of ```objc.
